# How do I access the source file name in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

I want to enable [code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis?view=vs-2019) using CMake and Ninja:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources *.cpp)

target_sources(${target}
    PRIVATE 
        ${sources}
)

target_compile_options(${target}
    PRIVATE
        -analyze:log report.xml
        -analyze:ruleset "${RuleSet}"
        -analyze:quiet
)
```

The generated build.ninja looks roughly as follows (omitting a lot of irrelevant data):

```
build foo.cpp.obj: CXX_COMPILER foo.cpp:
  FLAGS = -analyze:log report.xml -analyze:ruleset "C:\rulesets\MixedRecommendedRules.ruleset" -analyze:quiet

build bar.cpp.obj: CXX_COMPILER bar.cpp
  FLAGS = -analyze:log report.xml -analyze:ruleset "C:\rulesets\MixedRecommendedRules.ruleset" -analyze:quiet
```

The problem is that **each source file is compiled individually** and thus **the report gets overwritten** every time the compiler is invoked.

Is there any way to **include the source file name** like this:

```
target_compile_options(${target}
    PRIVATE
        -analyze:log report_{source_file}.xml
        -analyze:ruleset "${RuleSet}"
        -analyze:quiet
)
```

Comment: You could [iterate](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html) over all files in the `source` list, and [set the property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html#command:set_source_files_properties) individually.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322271/how-do-i-access-the-source-file-name-in-cmake#comment101135373_57322271) and ended up with the following:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources *.cpp)

target_sources(${target}
    PRIVATE 
        ${sources}
)

foreach(source_file ${sources})
    get_filename_component(file_name ${source_file} NAME)
    set_source_files_properties(${source_file} PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-analyze:log ${file_name}_report.xml")
endforeach()

target_compile_options(${target}
    PRIVATE
        -analyze:ruleset "${RuleSet}"
        -analyze:quiet
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is get the file name component from the file like this;

```
foreach (_src_file ${source})
  get_filename_component(_src_filename ${_src_file} NAME)
  target_compile_options(${target}
    PRIVATE
        -analyze:log report_${_src_filename}.xml
        -analyze:ruleset "${RuleSet}"
        -analyze:quiet
  )
endforeach()
```

main downside is that you need to check each file individually, and you cannot do it as a list, lik in your example above.

Maybe there are other options that would get what you require, have a look at [the get_filename_component documentation.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html)

Comment: I tried this but then all compiler flags specified in the `target_compile_options` section were missing in the build.ninja file.